# $routeProvider is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have added the scripts like this

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/test.js"></script>
```

and I did this in my `test.js`

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
});


app.controller('loginController', function () {

})
```

I got that the $routeProvider is unknown.

I have read many questions about this and I tried the solutions but nothing works.

help please

#### note

the angular library is working
I can make binding for example

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just tried that and I still got the same error

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rLwXg/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny you tested it by trying to binding in the login controller. Okay, I will try that in my machine. now my login.html is empty. In order to test that. should I put any angular markup in the login.html? or just `{{testme}}`?

Comment: see `<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="loginController">{{test}}</div>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I passed the scope to the function in the controller, and then run the page (it is test.html), then I wetn to login.html. but i got `{{test}}` not the actual string that I make in the controller

Comment: @ArunPJohny the error that routeprovider is unknown suddently gone ,but the test is not working

Comment: @ArunPJohny I got errro that `angular route min . map` is not exist. I can donwnload it but I am following the official page which doesn't state that I have to include this js. why pleaes?

Comment: that should be fine... it is used by the javascript debugger

Comment: what test is not working

Comment: @ArunPJohny the main problem that I asked for is solved by you, I will try to solve the other problems my self, please write an ansewr to accept it

Comment: I don't know what solved the problem :(

Comment: @ArunPJohny the website with example you gave point me out to the solution, just wrote that website and it is fine. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="loginController">{{test}}</div>
```

then

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
});


app.controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test me"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 1.2 - ngRoute module is separated as component, you have to include angular-route.js, then you will have your providers.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5599b55b04788c2e327d7551a4a699d75516dd21
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-12