# routeProvider is unknown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891058/routeprovider-is-unknown) but it seems like its *a different case*, I think for mine, angular module is *not binding to html somehow*.

Here are my code and error from console.

Please note that I am using gulp to combine all the ng .js file into /app.js

and the order of combining is [module.js , other*.js]
so

```
 angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

is always first to be defined.

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:78:12
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3741:19
    at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3869:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3896:13)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3824:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:320:11)
    at loadModules (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3811:5)
    at createInjector (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:3751:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js:1410:20)
```

**routes.js**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller : 'PostsCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'posts.html'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        controller : 'RegisterCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'register.html'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'login.hrml'
    })
})
```

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/app.css'>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.js'></script>
    <script src='/app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**module.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: Is `app.js` combined version of route.js and module.js

Comment: can't see your add the `routes.js` and `module.js` in the html

Comment: Sorry guys, im using gulp to combine all the ng .js files into /app.js

Comment: is it `/app.js` file loading correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is minified then you need to use the array injector.  Angular looks at how you named the variable to determine what dependency to pass to your application.

I've also changed how you started your app as I don't see module.js being loaded in the HTML

**app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/app.css'>
  </head>
  <body ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.js'></script>
    <script src='/app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);


app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller : 'PostsCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'posts.html'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        controller : 'RegisterCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'register.html'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'login.hrml'
    })
}]);
```

Comment: I used minified with gulp-uglify but i also used gulp-ng-annotate to handle that.

Comment: Edited the answer with the html and javascript file.

Comment: Actually, I had "var app = angular.module('app', [])" in another js file that is for ng-controller.. but I take you as answer for appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem,

**1 -**     `angular.module('app');`

**2 -**     `angular.module('app', []);`

**second module declaration** will create a brand new module and the bracket in the arguments is for the dependencies of the module to inject the dependencies.

**first module declaration** is not going to create a brand new module instead it will extends the previously created module, so for that there should be a existing module at this point.

here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

its says,

> When passed two or more arguments, a new module is created. If passed only one argument, an existing module (the name passed as the first argument to module) is retrieved.

**So** , may be your order of module declaration is wrong, you need to put `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);` on top of the `var app = angular.module('app');` and i cant see any use of `var app = angular.module('app');` line.

Comment: Actually, in gulp when I merge them, i put angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']) since it will create it and as you mention the one without [] is getter. Var app = angular.module('app') is just mistake while i was taking some parts of code to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this while looking for a solution to my problem.  I was / am working through J Dickey's "Write Modern Web Apps with the MEAN Stack"
and my file names, controller names, CDNs, Angular v1.2.18, gulp, etc. etc. are the same.  The post is over a year old, but I'm just now getting to this particular book & others with the same problem may well follow.

Everything was working just fine until chapter 8 "Adding Routing..." I added ngRoute & ng/routes.js ran $ gulp dev and was expecting the 404 error for the missing templates/posts.html, but got the: "Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider ..." error instead.

The problem I found was that in chapter 5 we broke up ng/app.js into separate pieces -- I wanted the original for comparison later. So I renamed it ng/app.bak.js and proceeded to pull the parts out into separate files with no problem.  In chapter 6 we added in automated build using gulp uglify, annotate, yada yada -- still no problem.  In chapter 7 the dependency for ngRoute was added and everything broke (just as the topic of this post).  I already knew what K.Torres said just above, but thanks to that post, I looked harder for at that possibly being the problem.

With my backup app.js in ng/ it was being combined with the original parts into the "uglified & annotated" assets/js/app.js like so:

```
angular.module("app",["ngRoute"]);angular.module("app",[]);...
```

ng/module.js consists of only "angular.module("app",["ngRoute"])" and is ordered 1st in the build process. The rest are added by wildcard matching on ng/**/*.js -- which included app.bak.js with ***no*** dependencies.  The second angular.module() was overwriting the first **without** the needed ngRoute dependency.

When I removed app.bak.js from ng/ then assets/js/app.js smooshes like so:

```
angular.module("app",["ngRoute"]),angular.module("app").controller...
```

then I was able to proceed as planned. 8)

My lesson: **Don't leave unneeded files in build folders.**

Hope this can help someone else. xD